# Should I using fully-qualified when import package? Does it cause any side effect?

Tags: java, string

I have this fragment of code.

```
 Objects.toString(record.getBuy(), org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.EMPTY);
```

I prefer using `EMPTY` constant over the string literal itself, but I'm already using another `StringUtils` class in my code and **Intellij** forces me to use a fully-qualified package name. I'm wondering it's still good to use or using "" ?

Comment: The first thing realized is pretty long name and this affects the readability.

Comment: It makes no difference to use fully qualified name.. But using a string constant is better.

Answer (score 2):

`EMPTY` is a static field, so you can use a `static` import:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.EMPTY;
import org.some.other.package.StringUtils;
```

And then your line of code becomes this:

```
Objects.toString(record.getBuy(), EMPTY);
```

I'm not sure you gain much from doing that. Some may argue this code is no more readable than your original. But it's an option.

**Edit**

The string literal `""` is the least surprising for readers of your code, I agree.

Regarding "does it cause any side effects?": `EMPTY` is defined in StringUtils as this (see [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/eb8d069089364e396e37ed5273cf7710e41eb06d/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#L149)):

```
public static final String EMPTY = "";
```

No side effects (i.e. no differences in behavior).

(I imagine it made sense in the `StringUtils` code to avoid excessive use of `""`, for clarity *in their specific context* - and to use a label such as `EMPTY` instead.)

Comment: Yeah. Another good idea. But I think it's better to use a string literal. Thank you.